# Which order functions would be called

Tags: c, function-calls

Is there some definite order in which the functions are called in the expression below or does it vary from compiler to compiler?

Does the following rule apply here - In C, the order in which arguments to functions and operands to most operators are evaluated is unspecified. Found the above rule in this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#Syntax)

```
a = (f1(10, 20) * f2(30, 40)) + f3()
```

Comment: @Mat - Thanks for pointing this out. Yes it is a duplicate question indeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule does apply. `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` may be evaluated in any order.

To expand a bit on some of the confusion (because people keep posting **wrong answers**), operator precedence does **not** affect the order in which things are *evaluated*. Take this example:

```
f1() * f2() + f3()
```

Now, we know that yes, the results of `f1()` and `f2()` are multiplied, and then added to the result of `f3()`, but we don't know the *order of evaluation*. The parse tree looks like this:

```
        +
      /   \
     *    f3()
   /   \
f1()   f2()
```

But we don't know if the left side or the right side of `+` will be evaluated first. It could be either way. Same with `*`: we don't know if its left side or right side will be evaluated first.

The compiler could call `f3()`, then store the result, then call `f2()`, store that result, and then call `f1()`, and then use the stored results to perform the actual computation.

Or, alternatively, it could call `f1()`, store the result, then call `f2()`, then use the two values to multiply (and then store that result), then call `f3()` and finish the computation.

In each of these cases (or any other permutation of evaluation order), the functions were evaluated in different order, and yet the same answer is achieved.

To conclude: **operator precedence determines the parse tree, *not* the order of evaluation**. The order in which the parse tree is evaluated is unspecified.

Comment: `operator precedence determines the parse tree, not the order of evaluation` It doesn't matter how parse tree is formed, compiler can still evaluate functions f1(), f2() and f3() in any order. Unspecified means *unspecified*. Parse tree doesn't prove or disprove anything.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Huh? That's what I was saying. "The order in which the parse tree is evaluated is unspecified." The whole reason I went on the "operator precedence determines parse tree" thing is because people kept posting wrong answers suggesting that operator precedence determines order of evaluation. I was informing people that that is incorrect, operator precedence has a different reason for existing (determining the parse tree), not order of evaluation.

Comment: You are saying that. But you are also saying something on parse tree which is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Exactly, yes, because people kept claiming that the parse tree was relevant, and I'm trying to prove to people that it's not relevant. You really should have seen all the wrong answers that were here before I posted this. It might help make the context a bit clearer.

Comment: Sorry...If that's in response to something else, I'll stop here!

Answer (score 4):

A compiler may call those functions in any order (that is, the only guarantee is that f1 and f2 are called before the multiplication,  and all three are called before the addition, and that all three will only be called after the value of their arguments is known).

With literal arguments like that,  the compiler may well call them as early as possible (like,  lines and lines above),  or even make them inline.

Most importantly,  don't confuse operator precedence with the order of function evaluation.

All you know is that the function will be called after the value of its arguments are known,  but before its return value is used.

Answer (score 2):

These functions can be evaluated in any order. There is no specified rule. Either `f1` is evaluated first then `f2` and then `f3` or `f3` is evaluated first then `f2` and then `f1` or `f2` is evaluated first then `f1` and then `f3` or even `f1` is evaluated first then `f3` and then `f2` (total of six combinations here!).

One thing note here that: **Operator precedence has nothing to do with the order of evaluation**.

But keep in mind that what ever be the order of evaluation of these functions the arithmetic operation on the expression

```
a = (f1(10, 20) * f2(30, 40)) + f3()
```

will take palace according to the operator precedence rule, i.e, `f1*f2` takes place first (at the time `f1` and `f2` must be evaluated) and then the result of this is added to `f3` (all `f1`, `f2` and `f2` must be evaluated).

Comment: See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Theroretically, `f3` could even be in the middle - but I don't see any useful reason for that. (Ok, depending on platform and register usage and other circumstances, even that might be relevant...)

Comment: @FiddlingBits; I did't downvote your answer but the first line of your answer was wrong which I supposed tempted users to downvote.

Comment: @haccks What makes you think I did? I even upvoted you!

Comment: @glglgl; Oh. Sorry! My apologies. I don't know who downvoted this. If something is wrong with this answer then he should comment about it. (I was thinking that this statement: `Theroretically, f3 could even be in the middle` was the reason of your downvote).