# Equality operator precedence not working

Tags: c++, associativity

In C++, the equality operator's associativity is left to right, as stated [here](http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_operators.html) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and the returned value of an assignment operation is the value assigned to the given variable. (As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697643/low-level-details-of-c-c-assignment-operator-implementation-what-does-it-retu), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292892/what-is-return-type-of-assignment-operator), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514569/what-does-an-assignment-return), and [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), (section 6.5.16, pages 101-104 for the last link).)

According to this information, this:

```
double d = 5;

if (d == (d = 6))
    cout << "but d was 5...!!!" << endl;
else
    cout << "5!=6 :)" << endl;
```

should print `"5!=6 :)"` since the expression, `(d == (d = 6))` is equivalent to `(5 == (6))` (which is false), but instead, `"but d was 5..."` is printed. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Operator associativity doesn't tell you in what order the operands are evaluated. It tells you how they're grouped/parsed.

Comment: @Galik: That's false. They **do not** force any order of evaluation.

Comment: You might want to read up on [What is associativity of operators and why is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930486/what-is-associativity-of-operators-and-why-is-it-important) I also suggest reading [my answer about operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20756163/1287251) where I explain how the precedence/associativity affects the compiler's parsing of the code, but not the order of evaluation of arguments.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour (the assignment is unsequenced with respect to the left-hand operand of `==`)

Comment: Please decide on a language. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: Don't tag multiple languages, please. That's spam. If your code compiles using a C compiler and you want to ask about C, use the C tag. Otherwise, if you need a C++ compiler to compile your code or you want to ask about C++, use the C++ tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing associativity with order of evaluation.

Left-to-right associativity means

```
a == b == c
```

is interpreted as

```
(a == b) == c
```

That has no relationship with order of evaluation of terms in an expression like `a == b`. The compiler is free to evaluate `a` and `b` in any order. Because of that, in your case, the compiler is free to evaluate `d` first or `(d = 6)` first. As a consequence, your program can evaluate to `true` or `false` depending which side of the operator gets evaluated first. If there is a race condition (a compiler is free to evaluate them in parallel also), the result will be different from one run to the next.

Comment: Just for clarification is the behavior undefined, or merely unspecified?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Is there any way to force the order of evaluation to my liking?

Comment: @MarkB, the quote in [the answer by Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44491199/434551) indicates that it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Kröw, there may be ways of doing that but I am not sure what your end goal is in this particular case.

Comment: I think the intent was `if (d != 6) { cout << "d was 5\n"; d = 6; } else { cout << "d was 6\n"; }`.  In this case you could use `if ( d++ != 6 )` but only because 5 and 6 differ by 1. Note - equality comparison for floating point may be unreliable.

Comment: @RSahu I have a while loop which sets a variable equal to a value and continues running **only** if the value is not already equal to the variable.

Comment: @Kröw, is there is a driving need to combine the "set the value of the variable" and "compare the value of the variable with another value" into one statement? It will be simpler to separate them, IMO.

Comment: @RSahu Mostly efficiency. One statement lowers the amount of processing by a large amount. However, it really isn't necessary at all; I made my code work after separating it, but if there is a way to do this in one statement, I'd like to know how, in case I need it later on.

Comment: @Kröw, I would be very surprised if that change will be a factor in performance of your program. If it does, a better place to ask questions related to improving performance will be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @RSahu Ok, but apart from that, do you know of a way to accomplish the above?

Comment: @Kröw, I still can't visualize the logic you are trying to implement. It might be better to post that in another question, with more details.

Answer (score 6):

The relevant part of the standard is this:

> **[intro.execution]/15** Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially concurrent (1.10), the behavior is undefined.**

Emphasis mine. Your program exhibits undefined behavior because there's a modification of `d` (in the right-hand side of the comparison) unsequenced with the value computation of `d` (in the left-hand side of the same). Associativity and precedence don't enter into this.

Comment: Also, operands of `==` are unsequenced  (people coming from other languages tend to assume that there is something like left-right sequencing for operators and function calls)

Comment: @M.M Isn't it right there in the first sentence? *"evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced."* Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I am saying that `==` does not have an "except where noted" exception!