# Prefix vs Postfix with relational operator in C. How does operator associativity affect?

Tags: c

According to associativity rules, ++prefix is Right to Left associative, while postfix++ is Left to Right associative. In the code below, I tried both of those options together with a relational (<) check. But the answer I received seems counterintuitive. Could someone clear this up for me?

In this statement:

```
(++i < 5)
```

I expect that

```
"++i"
```

to be interpreted first since it has has Right to Left associativity and a higher precedence than "<", and then

```
"++i < 5"
```

to be interpreted. Instead, the opposite occurs. Below is the full program I used to try this out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (++i < 5)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
    puts("");
    while (j++ < 5)
    {
        printf("%d ", j);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I receive the following outputs for the program:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: First, associativity and precedence don't determine order of evaluation. Second, `++i` and `j++` do the same thing, with the exception that the former returns the new (incremented) value of `i` and the latter returns the old (pre-increment) value of `j`.

Comment: What determines order of evaluation then if not precedence?

Comment: [Order of evaluation is, generally, unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order). Yes, the arguments `++i` and `5` must each be evaluated first before the operator `<` can be evaluated, but that's not because of associativity or precedence. Imagine operator `<` being replace with a function named `less_than` that takes two arguments, and you call it with `less_than(++i, 5)`. Both arguments must be evaluated before the function can be called and evaluated itself, but the order of evaluation of the arguments is unspecified and isn't determined by associativity or precedence.

Comment: I get what you mean in terms of viewing the statement as a "less_than" function, where the arguments must be evaluated prior to the function. But isn't the fact that "++i" in  "++i < 5" is evaluated prior to "<5" related to/determined by the precedence table? While "j++" in "j++ < 5" is evaluated after "j < 5" ? In the "j++ < 5" statement, the function idea doesn't hold up as before. Or simply that there are now 2 nested functions: "plus_plus(less_than(j, 5))"? But isn't that related to precedence?

Comment: First, in the expression `++i < 5`, *both* `++i` and `5` are evaluated first before `<`. This isn't because of precedence or associativity. This is because operator`<` requires two arguments and cannot be evaluated without first evaluating the arguments (just like a function call). Also `j++` is *not* evaluated after `j < 5`. It is evaluated just like the function call `less_than(j++, 5)` (so both `j++` and `5` will be evaluated before the function call `less_than`).

Comment: In the case of `j++`, it seems that it is evaluated after `j < 5`, because just by looking at the output of the code I used, in the second "while loop", the program enters the loop in the 5th iteration and prints out the number 5 despite the fact that `j++ < 5` is false if `j++ == 5`.

Comment: I think you're slightly misunderstanding what `++i` and `j++` do. `j++` modifies the value of `j` and increments it, but returns the old (non-incremented) value of `j`. It doesn't delay the increment of `j`. [I don't know if this demo helps at all, but I hope it might](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oRzy4q). [Or perhaps an old answer of mine might be slightly helpful, though it doesn't cover pre-/post-increment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20756163).

Comment: That's perfect, clears it up very nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In `++i < 5`, the `++i` is indeed evaluated first.  I don't know why you think that's not happening.

In `j++ < 5`, the value of the expression `j++` is also evaluated first, but the value of the expression is the pre-incremented value (and the increment might actually happen a bit later, but that's another story).  `j++` is pretty much like `(++j - 1)`.

Comment: you're right, after looking over for the 10th time, now I see that. Sorry it was a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Associativity for unary operators is meaningless, since they are unary operators. Associativity is a feature of binary operators, by definition.

It's conventional to mark postfix operators as right associative and prefix operators as left associative. No doubt there is a reason for this convention but in practice it really doesn't matter. [Note 1]

In any case, precedence is not really related to evaluation order. In `f(a)+f(b)*f(c)` the three calls to `f` could occur in any order, and `f(a)` could be called before or after the multiplication. Obviously, an operand must be evaluated before the operator which uses it can be applied (except for short-circuiting operators), but that's only tangentially related to precedence. Precedence really only tells you where you would have to put parentheses if you wanted to make the expression unambiguous.

#### Notes

1. If you are using bison/yacc's precedence feature (if not, just ignore this note) and you didn't want to manually tag prefix productions with `%prec PREFIX`, then you might choose to mark *all* unary operators as right-associative at the same precedence level. That would make postfix operators bind more tightly than prefix operators, which is the usual convention. Hiwever, it's more common (and, I think, more sensible) to put them into different levels, making the precedence more explicit. Operators with more than one syntax (prefix/infix `-` or prefix/postfix `++` then need to have their prefix versions marked with `%prec`. None of this has any formal significance.